# Inserting the elements in grid column wise and creating different controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am new to Asp.net and C#.I am working in a project where I need to create GridView.Now I wanted to bind this column wise with the data.Like the column1 in the grid is "Category" in the table of database and so on. I also want to create the Hyperlink on the basis of the content in database for example I want to show the text of Hyperlink as "This is Java program" and URL specifies as "http://blogs.article?id=1".Please tell me that how I can do that.Currently I am able to bind the all three columns in the table to the three columns in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the HyperLinkField class. This should provide exactly what you're looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx

Comment: But I also want to get the content from the column in database and create the Hyperlink accordingly.Actually I am looking for binding the grid column wise rather binding it entirely.